# Problems displaying directions on button click using Aangular JS and the Google Maps JS API

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

Have been trying to get a button to work on in a small app that I have been building using the Ionic Framework.

The button has a pretty simple job right now, on click show directions on the map. When the function is called within the controller it shows on the map but when I try to call it from the click, I am not able to get the directions showing.

Wondering what the issue could be here.

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  map: $scope.map
});

$scope.show_dirs = function(){

var request = {
  destination: locations[3],
  origin: temp_center,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    // Display the route on the map.
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
};
//show function works
//$scope.show_dirs();
```

The HTML button:

```
    <div style= "position: absolute; bottom: -10px; width: 100%" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
      <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click = "show_dirs">Find Parking Near Me</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you trying to call the `show_dirs()` function from your button click? Post the markup or event listener code.

Comment: trying to call that function from the button click

Comment: Yes, you said that. But I am not sure what you mean by that. For example, are you using `ng-click`, `.addEventListener()`, `onclick`, `.on('click', ...)`, etc. Please show all of the relevant code in your question so we can find the problem. It may not be where you think it is, so post all of the relevant code and let us find it.

Comment: sorry, using ng-click in the button tag

Comment: *fist palms over and over again*

Comment: If I have helped you, please accept the answer and optionally upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-click` attribute is incorrect. It should be an Angular *expression* to evaluate and execute when the button is clicked.

What you have, `show_dirs`, will evaluate to the function itself. What you want instead is to actually *call* that function.

So it should be `ng-click="show_dirs()"`.